# Objective-C Cocoa how to correctly use run loop in GCD

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I'm not sure how to correctly use GCD in a run loop situation where the thread might need to be stopped. The problem starts from the outset, and how or where to use CGEventCallback (which is absent from my code). The stop button won't stop the loop, and I don't think my dispatch queue is setup properly -- along with the while loop creating a huge lag.

I've read top question-answers from the search, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13712299/3929449) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3255428/3929449), but one is for iOS and the other isn't relevant. Could someone show me how to properly do this?

my code:

// .h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {

    IBOutlet NSTextField *textFieldBox;
    IBOutlet NSButton *stop;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

- (void)stop;

@end
```

// .m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

BOOL isActive = FALSE;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self mainMethod];
}

- (void)mainMethod {

    NSLog(@"loop started");
    isActive = TRUE;
    [self theArbitraryNonCompliantLoop];
    NSLog(@"doing other stuff");
}

- (void)stop {

    isActive = FALSE;
    return;
}

- (void)theArbitraryNonCompliantLoop {

    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

        while (isActive) {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            [textFieldBox setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)i]];
            }
        }
    });
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the name, the for loop needs to test `isActive` as well.  That will solve the latency issue.

The UI update needs to be done on the main thread which is easy because you can just schedule a block on the main queue to do it.

```
- (void)theArbitraryNonCompliantLoop {

    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

        while (isActive) 
        {
            for (NSUInteger i = 0; isActive && i < 1000000; i++) 
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                               ^{ [textFieldBox setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)i]] };
            }
        }
    });
}
```

There are still some issues here.  I think, as it stands it will flood the main thread's run loop with events, so some throttling will be required.  You might also consider some synchronisation for the `inActive` instance variable in case the compiler optimises it by pulling it into a register at the beginning of the method.  Also, it will be subject to race conditions thanks to caching etc.

Comment: thanks, your help allowed me to understand this more, and it works now. i ended up doing it slightly different - but the text is updating smoothly and the button stops it, so i appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Big mistake: You are changing a UI element on a background thread. That will cause all kinds of problems. Don't do that.

You seem to be quite confused what a runloop is. You are also trying to confuse people by calling something "theRunLoop" that just does stuff on a background thread. Your code has nothing to do with the runloop, and until you understand what a runloop is, better keep away from it.

Comment: this answer doesn't help. i already know my code is incorrect, that is why i asked the question. i'm trying to find a solution to the problem, or something i can learn from. you don't explain 'all kinds of problems' and i'm not 'trying' to confuse anybody, this is not a runloop either i suppose? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4948163/3929449 thanks

Comment: @Y.Harris the bit about not doing UI updates on threads other than the main one is at least part of the answer.

Comment: @JeremyP, thank you. so are you saying that i need to do the ui updates on the main thread only, and would that not lock the ability for a user to interact with anything until it was finished?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you call an arbitrary method `theRunLoop`?

Either way, quoting **Run Loops** ([*Threading Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html)):

> Both Cocoa and Core Foundation provide run loop objects to help you
>   configure and manage your thread’s run loop. Your application does not
>   need to create these objects explicitly; each thread, including the
>   application’s main thread, has an associated run loop object. Only
>   secondary threads need to run their run loop explicitly, however. The
>   app frameworks automatically set up and run the run loop on the main
>   thread as part of the application startup process.

Comment: who cares. i just want it to work. i changed the name, happy now?

Comment: This should really be a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your while loop is still on its first run. The 1000000 for loop is probably taking too long which is why it still seems like the loop is still running. To test it out put an NSLog after your for loop to see if it has exited it after you changed isActive to false.

Comment: the while loop just restarts and isActive is always true. thanks

Comment: @Y.Harris That reminds me, to change a variable inside a block you have to add the `_block` identifier although I'm not sure if that applies to objects/GDC. I would guess that might be your problem, try playing around with that.